# Probability question - statistics

Tags: probability, statistics

Could somebody please help me, I have been trying to calculate this problem all day, but with no success. Here is the problem:

"A teacher was asked by her principal to select 7
students at random from her class to help out on an outing to a
senior's home. In her class, she has 5 girls and 6 boys.  The
principal believes that this teacher always favors the girls when it
comes to outings such as this.  When the teacher handed in her list
of student names, the principal noted that the number of girls on the
list was 5 and the number of boys was 2.  Is there any statistical
evidence that the teacher favors girls?
Compute the probability that, of the students selected, 2 are girls.
Round off to 4 decimal places."

I tried to calculate it as follows:

$$\left ( \frac{6}{11} \right )\left ( \frac{5}{10} \right )\left ( \frac{4}{9} \right )\left ( \frac{3}{8} \right )\left ( \frac{2}{7} \right )\left ( \frac{5}{6} \right )\left ( \frac{4}{5} \right )=.0087$$

and I also tried a second method:

$$7\left ( \frac{6}{11} \right )\left ( \frac{5}{10} \right )\left ( \frac{4}{9} \right )\left ( \frac{3}{8} \right )\left ( \frac{2}{7} \right )\left ( \frac{5}{6} \right )\left ( \frac{4}{5} \right )=.0606$$

but, the Mathematica program we are using in university tells me that both of these answers are wrong. Please help me solve this problem. This is time sensitive, so somebody please respond as soon as possible and show me the whole solution. Thank you, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Shouldn't you compute the probability that two are boys instead?

Comment: I am not sure why you are saying that because the problem is specifically asking for the probability of 2 girls being chosen.

Comment: I am trying to find the solution to this problem. Could you please read what the problem is asking before responding? Thanks.

Comment: There are $N=\binom{11}{7}$ ways to select $7$ students. If the selection is done at random, these are equally likely. The number of ways to select $2$ girls (and therefore $5$ boys) is $F=\binom{5}{2}\binom{6}{5}$. The probability of $2$ girls (not suitable for dealing with the favouring issue) is $\frac{F}{N}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little confusing because at first you state that all $5$ girls are chosen then you ask what is the probability that $2$ girls are chosen so what was the point of mentioning $5$ girls chosen?

If the $7$ student choices are truly random then we have the following:

$5 \choose 2$ * $6 \choose 5$ / $11 \choose 7$ = $2/11$ = $.1818$...  Your first calculation is off by a factor of $21$ (too low) and your 2nd calculation is off by a factor of $3$ (also too low).

$5 \choose 2$ * $6 \choose 5$ / $11 \choose 7$ = $(6*5*4*24) / (2*11*10*9*8)$ = $(6/11)(5/10)(4/9)(24/16)$ using your format.

A $.1818$ probability doesn't make me suspicious of favoritism however if all $5$ girls (of $5$) and only $2$ of $6$ boys were chosen (which is $1/4$ as likely as choosing $2$ girls and $5$ boys), that seems like favoritism.  However "statistically speaking", a one time occurrence of this doesn't show a pattern of favoritism.

Comment: Thank you very much David, you helped me a lot I really appreciate it!

Comment: You're welcome, glad I was a help but Andre Nicolas comment helped me to confirm my answer so some credit should go there so give him a useful comment "tick" and I will too.